# How do I silently mount AFP shares on OS X 10.5 clients?

Tags: mac, share, afp, silent

I can add the share to the login startup items, but it always pops open Finder. I want the AFP share to mount silently. This is in a Mac computer lab with the Macs joined to AD.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with smb shares and will double check tonight when i get home but iirc you need to write some simple applescript to mount the volume

IIRC the following will work

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "afp://machine_name/path"
end tell
```

Compile it into an application and add that to the login items

Comment: Sorry i forgot to grab the install disk on my way home this arvo if i remember I will test this tomorrow morning

Comment: That script seems to open Finder as well.

Comment: Ok this is rather odd. I've tested it at work and something must be different on our SOE as I don't get a window popping up with afp or cifs connections.

Answer (score 0):

You just tick the "Hide"-button in the Start Objects-screen on System Preferences>Accounts, and it shouldn't show a Finder for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer and I found a cleaner way to do that using the automounter daemon.

In short you should create a `/etc/fstab` file, (you does need root privileges to do that) and put this line into that file

```
(hostname):(share) (mount_point) url automounted,url==afp://(username):(password)@(hostname)/(share) (mount_point) 0 0
```

You should replace values between parentheses with your values and then you have to restart the automounter daemon with

```
$ sudo automount -vc
```

from Terminal.app. Alternatively you can reboot to activate new settings. If you did it in the shell way the previous command should respond with something like

```
~> sudo automount -vc
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: /Volumes/Shared mounted <-- This line refers to the share I've mounted
automount: no unmounts
```

After that you should find your mounted folder in the Finder automatically.

Some references I found:

- http://rajeev.name/2007/11/22/autofs-goodness-in-apples-leopard-105-part-i/
- http://rajeev.name/2007/11/23/autofs-goodness-in-apples-leopard-105-part-ii/
- http://www.kristijan.org/2010/11/automount-afp-shares-in-osx/

P.S. If you're not a Terminal.app fan you can use [this GUI app](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29844/bonjour-mounter) to automount filesystems, I haven't tried it because it's not free, but if you need that is pretty cheap.